# How to get the result of a celery periodic running task?

Tags: task, celery

when the periodic task is running , how to get the task return? I need the running result.

this is my problem:

For example, my periodic task:

```
@shared_task(name='add')
def add():
    x=1,y=2
    return x+y
```

I add the task as periodic task from django admin,then start the worker with -B DEBUG option.It runs well.But I want to get the return value.Is there any method to get the retult when the periodic task is running?

Comment: You should provide some code examples showing what you have tried and what's exactly your issue.

Comment: Did you set in your settings `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` ?

Comment: yes,i have already set the CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="amqp".Periodic task stoers the result in rabbitmq? How to get it ?

Comment: thank you @daniula,i am a freshman of stackoverflow.I did not find the button or link to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

To get result of a task you can call `.get()` method on `AsyncResult` object, which is returned when you add task to a queue:

```
result = add.delay()
result.get() // returns 5
```

Also make sure that your results are stored for enough long time by setting up `CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT` or `CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES`. Read more in [AMQP backend settings](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#conf-amqp-result-backend) section.